# Lesscss data-uri output

Tags: svg, less

According to http://lesscss.org/functions/ `data-uri('image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8', 'image.svg');` should output `url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%3E%3Ccircle%20r%3D%229%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");`

Tested here https://codepen.io/ZeGregg/pen/RwoOqLG?editors=1100 and compiled css output `background-image: url("https://getuikit.com/assets/uikit/src/images/icons/cloud-download.svg");`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks to the community

Comment: ``image/svg+xml`` requires a string input, not a reference to filename; use **svg data uri** search to find good examples here on SO

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman thanks. I will make other search but If you are right Lesscss official documentation is wrong http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-data-uri

Comment: Ah, sorry, it wasn't clear to me it was a ``data-uri`` **function** with 2 parameters..